# How to store and display datetime field of a Model according to the end user's location in django?

Tags: html, django, datetime, timezone

models.py

```js
class PostModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}
    {{post.date_time}}
    <br>
    {{post.title}}
    <br>
    {{post.body}}
    <br>
    {% for image in post.imagespostmodel_set.all %}
        <img src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
        <br>
    {% endfor %}

    <hr>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have to specifically set the timezone in setting.py, but I want to display the time according the user location.

Answer (score 0):

Django has inbuilt functionality for handling timezones. Reading the documentation at [Django Timezone Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) should help you out. An example is provided there.